# Webkit 3D perspective bugs

Tags: html, css, webkit, 3d, perspective

I'm playing around with browsers lately, and now I'm fighting with 3D. WebGL is awesome, and I can do 3D in CSS3 too? Even better! Ok, so my vision was to create floating 3D objects using nested transformations (with preserve-3d).

HTML

```
<div class="scene">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="side_1"></div>
        <div class="side_2"></div>
        <div class="side_3"></div>
        <div class="side_4"></div>
        <div class="side_5"></div>
        <div class="side_6"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="side_1"></div>
        <div class="side_2"></div>
        <div class="side_3"></div>
        <div class="side_4"></div>
        <div class="side_5"></div>
        <div class="side_6"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="side_1"></div>
        <div class="side_2"></div>
        <div class="side_3"></div>
        <div class="side_4"></div>
        <div class="side_5"></div>
        <div class="side_6"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="side_1"></div>
        <div class="side_2"></div>
        <div class="side_3"></div>
        <div class="side_4"></div>
        <div class="side_5"></div>
        <div class="side_6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS (I'm using prefixfree)

```
.scene {
    perspective: 3500;
    perspective-origin: 25% 100%;
    animation: spin 15s infinite linear;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    width: 960px;
    height: 350px;
    margin: 80px auto;
}

.box {
    width: 150px;
    height: 180px; 
    position: absolute;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;  
    top: 40px;  
}
.box div {
    width: 150px;
    height: 180px;
    opacity: 0.75;
    background-color: #bada55;
    position: absolute;    
}
.box .side_1   { 
    transform: rotateY(   0deg ) translateZ( 75px );     
    background-color: #FF0;
}
.box .side_2   { 
    transform: rotateX( 180deg ) translateZ( 75px ); 
    background-color: #F00;
}
.box .side_3   { 
    transform: rotateY(  90deg ) translateZ( 75px );    
    background-color: #CCC; }
.box .side_4   {
    transform: rotateY( -90deg ) translateZ( 75px ); 
    background-color: #000;
}
.box .side_5   { 
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #00a2ff;
    transform: rotateX(  90deg ) translateZ( 75px ); }
.box .side_6   { 
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #00a2ff;
    width: 150px;
    transform: rotateX( -90deg ) translateZ( 105px ); }
.box:first-child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
}
.box:last-child {
    right: 0;
}
.box:nth-child(2) {
    background: url(../img/dot.jpg) repeat-y center center transparent;
    transform: translateZ( -600px );
    left: 480px;
}
.box:nth-child(3) {
    background: url(../img/dot.jpg) repeat-y center center transparent;
    transform: translateZ( 600px );
    left: 480px;
}

@keyframes spin {
    0%   { transform: rotateY(0); }    
    100%   { transform: rotateY(360deg); }
}
```

Everything is set up, and works. But wait, what is happening? Why does the far object is bigger than close one? I don't understand. Is it webkit bug, or I'm missing something?

http://stretchbox.org/projects/Nextgen/floaters.php - here you have an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.scene` is also rotating, so you need to apply the perspective and perspective-origin on its parent, which in your case would be body.

```
body {
    perspective: 3500;
    perspective-origin: 25% 100%;
}
```

You can see a demo here:

http://jsfiddle.net/dw58P/embedded/result/

Nice project by the way!